# jquery: Call function by name on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to call a function by name `.onchange` of a select but nothing happens. When the function is describled after the attribute, it works.

**THIS DOESN'T WORK**

HTML:

```
<select id="numb">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#numb').change(testMessage);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function testMessage(){
        alert('Hello');
    }
</script>
```

**THIS WORKS**

HTML:

```
<select id="numb">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#numb').change(function(){
      alert('Hello')
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, for all those who said me to include the function on the same script. This is not possible because the `testMessage()` function is in an external `.js` script included on the `<head>` of the HTML.

Comment: What's your console say? Something like `testMessage isn't defined`?

Comment: you should really do your event binding inside a document.ready function

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FMynS/

Comment: @JonnySooter The issue is the multiple `<script>` elements. Hoisting doesn't work across them: http://jsfiddle.net/WL87H/

Comment: From the edits: `function is in an external .js script included on the <head> of the HTML.`

Comment: Is `$('#numb').change(testMessage);` in a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Can you move your .JS files to the bottom of the body of the HTML or do you not control that. It is a best practice

Comment: no, it's not on document ready. I already tried to move it to the bottom, it's not working

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is because the handler `testMessage` is not defined when binding it to the change event.

It should work if it was in the same script context like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#numb').change(testMessage);

    function testMessage(){
        alert('Hello');
    }
</script>
```

Code inside `<script></script>` are executed one by one progressive from top and `testMessage` function doesn't exist inside the first `<script></script>`.

You have couple of options here,

1. Put it inside an anonymous function which will let your script to resolve the `testMessage` function later. [As suggested in [Optimus Prime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18239438/297641) answer]

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#numb').change(function () { 
        testMessage
     });
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function testMessage(){
         alert('Hello');
      }
   </script>
   ```
2. Include the script that has `testMessage` function above the `script` that binds the testMessage like below,

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function testMessage(){
       alert('Hello');
   }
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#numb').change(testMessage);
   </script>
   ```

Comment: @Perocat Wrap it inside the anonymous function. The handler function `testMessage` is required to be resolved when binding to onchange event, but not the content of the handler function.

Answer (score 6):

Instead try  ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#numb').change(function(){
       testMessage();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Perocat The handler function is required to be resolved when binding, but not the content of the handler function.

Comment: @Perocat The anonymous function delays the dereference of `testMessage`. By then, it will have been defined.

Comment: Is this a good/correct solution, or the delay could be to short?

Comment: @Perocat could be short, as you can see in Vega's answer.

Comment: @Perocat You could change the script execution order if it is simpler.. moving the script that has the handler function above the script which bind the function.

Comment: From my edits: `for all those who said me to include the function on the same script. This is not possible because the testMessage() function is in an external .js script included on the <head> of the HTML.`

Comment: @Perocat Then, you may either load js with this function before the jquery here or just use method in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Working Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuGmt/)
try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#numb').on('change',testMessage);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and place in the same script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#numb').change(testMessage);

        function testMessage(){
            alert('Hello');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define a callback on the change function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#numb').change(function(){
        testMessage(); 
    );

    function testMessage(){
        alert('Hello');
    }
</script>
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your reference exists yet to the function here is two ways you could do it.
I put the namespaced version as a suggestion because it might help clean up your code in general.

HTML:

```
<select id="numb">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

SCRIPT:

// Namespaced and using Proxy

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var project = project || {};
    project = {
        testMessage: function (event) {
           alert('Hello');
        }
    };

    $('#numb').change($.proxy(project.testMessage, project));
</script>
```

// Just declared

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testMessage(){
      alert('Hello');
    }

    $('#numb').change(function(event) {
       testMessage();
    });
</script>
```

If your method is in another file make sure you include that file before the one with the event binding. Are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value whenever you changed the value.

```
<select id="numb" onchange="Selecteditems()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

 var Selecteditems = function () {
            var items= $('#numb').val();
alert(items)
          
        }
```