# onChange method not working with Thymeleaf select option

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, thymeleaf

I am working on a Spring Boot + Thymeleaf project. I have `side-bar.html` file, fragments from which are used in other HTML files to avoid rewriting the code.

There is a *select option* element in `side-bar.html` which is populated with client ids.

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" th:fragment="side-bar-menu">
    <select id="clientId" name="clientId" class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" onchange="setCltVal(this);">
            <option value="">Choose or Type Client code</option>
            <option th:each="aclient : ${session.assignedClientList}" th:value="${aclient.cltcd+'|'+aclient.cname}" th:text="${aclient.cltcd+' - '+aclient.cname}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have included this fragment in `index.html`file.

```
<!-- sidebar menu -->
<div th:replace="fragments/side_bar :: side-bar-menu"></div>
```

Now I am trying to make an ajax call when any of the *select* options are selected to save them in the session object. For this I have provided a js script in `index.html`.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
console.log($('#clientId'));
function setCltVal() {
    var clientData = $("#clientId option:selected");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "setClientData",
        data: "clientData="+clientData,
        success: function(response){
            ...
           },
        error: function(error){
            ...
           }
        });
    }
</script>
```

But this script is never called when a select option is selected.

I also tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#clientId').on("change", function() {
    var clientData = $("#clientId").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "setClientData",
        data: "clientData="+clientData,
        success: function(response){
           ...
          },
        error: function(error){
           ...
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I want to achieve through this code is:
When any of the select options is selected, the script is called which makes ajax call to the controller and saves the client data in the session object.

I have referred [JavaScript + Thymeleaf - select onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556241/javascript-thymeleaf-select-onchange), [Thymeleaf select option](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-selected-not-working-on-lt-select-gt-lt-option-gt-td4029201.html) and [jquery: Call function by name on select change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239387/jquery-call-function-by-name-on-select-change), but didn't get the expected result.

I would sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: can you `console.log($('#clientId'))` to make sure the element is getting picked up correctly?

Comment: @Bricky That didn't give any output on the console.

Comment: Did you put it before the function that executes on change, or inside it?

If you put it before and it didn't output *anything* then your javascript file isn't being executed, or is running into an error earlier on.

If you put it inside, then move it a line above and try.

Comment: @Bricky I placed it before the function.Edited my code to show the same.

Comment: Try changing your eventListener to 
`$(document).on("change", "#clientId",  function() {`

Also add something else to the console.log just as a sanity check, like `console.log($('#clientId'), 'hello world');`

Comment: @Bricky That too didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

onChange method with Thymeleaf select option and jquery

```js
$("table #libelleArticle").change(function() { 
  // Add action of select option
  $("#prix").val("2000 euro");  
});
```

```html
 <td th:field="*{listArticles}">
   <select class="custom-select" id="libelleArticle" name="libelleArticle" >
      <option value=""> Selectionner un article </option>
      <option th:each="article : ${listArticles}" id="selectArt" th:value="${article.libelleArticle}" th:text="${article.libelleArticle}" />
   </select>
</td>
 
<td> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prix" name="prix" /> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should wait till the document is loaded before setting events. Wrap the JS call inside document ready function and try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
     $('#clientId').on("change", function() {
            console.log($('#clientId option:selected').val());
            // your ajax call
     });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `th:onchange` event instead of `onchange` event only. Like

```
th:onchange="'setCltVal(this)'";
```